# PHP public folder

Tags: php, public

I have been seeing several PHP online tutorials where they recommend that you have a public folder where you have your index.php and other views, css, js, etc and another folder (usually called app) where you have your classes and such. The idea is for the site to use the public folder as default so no one will be able to access the classes. The question is, once I upload the public and app folders to my server, how do I get the users to public/index.php when they type in mypage.com (without them having to type mypage.com/public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess file, Place it in root folder of your website:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```